# How to create a reminder and store reminder on iPhone Calender

Tags: ios, objective-c, datetime, alarm, reminders

I am new to programming I have made a Reminder App which saves the events on iCal and now i want to delete that events through the coding in the project, my code for creating events in iCal is below-

```
-(void) setReminderInPhone {
NSString *dateWithTime = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",calenderDtl.dateInString,calenderDtl.openTimeUTC];
NSString *mrktName = mrktDtl.marketName;
//dateWithTime = @"2016-04-02 04:10 am";

NSDateFormatter *fmt = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
fmt.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a";
[fmt setAMSymbol:@"am"];
[fmt setPMSymbol:@"pm"];
fmt.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"];
NSDate *utc = [fmt dateFromString:dateWithTime];

fmt.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a";
fmt.timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
NSString *local = [fmt stringFromDate:utc];
NSDate *localDate = [fmt dateFromString:local];
EKEventStore *store = [EKEventStore new];
[store requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
    if (!granted) { return; }
    EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:store];
    event.title = mrktName;
    event.startDate = localDate; //test
    event.endDate = [event.startDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*2];
    event.calendar = [store defaultCalendarForNewEvents];
    NSError *err = nil;
    [store saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:YES error:&err];
}];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try following to remove event from Calendar.

```
EKEvent *eventToRemove = [eventStore eventWithIdentifier:eventIdentifier];

if (eventToRemove)
{
    NSError* error = nil;

    [eventStore removeEvent:eventToRemove span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:YES error:&error];
}
```

You will get the Value of eventIdentifier at the time of creating event in iCalendar as following :

```
//Adding Events to default iOS calendar for Making Reminders
-(NSString *)addEventToCalendar: (NSString *)title withDate:(NSString *)date{

EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];

event.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Pregnancy Workout Advisor - Event: %@",title];

event.startDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:date];

event.endDate = [event.startDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60];  //set 1 hour meeting

event.allDay = YES;

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd"];

EKAlarm *alarm = [EKAlarm alarmWithAbsoluteDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:9*60*60 sinceDate:[dateFormatter dateFromString:date]]];

[event addAlarm:alarm];

event.calendar = [eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents];

NSError *err = nil;

[eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:YES error:&err];

return event.eventIdentifier;  }
```

In this above method, you will get a eventIdentifier for each event which you're adding to calendar. Store the eventIdentifier to CoreData/Sqlite, whatever..

So that, when you need to delete that event, just give that eventIdentifier. This will surely delete from Calendar.

Hope it helps...

Comment: First, we are getting Event entry from eventStore. If you have event on that day, then we proceed to removeEvent.

Comment: i am doing this but not able to remove  EKEventStore* store = [EKEventStore new]; [store requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError error) { if (!granted) { return;} EKEvent eventToRemove = [store eventWithIdentifier:savedEventId]; if (eventToRemove) { NSError* error = nil; [store removeEvent:eventToRemove span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:YES error:&error]; } }]; there is no error but it doen not grants permission simply return.

Comment: i/m not able to apply your code in my piece of code

Comment: thankyou so much its working :) but there is one problem that events get deleted from icalender only when app is open and also we are getting data from server so data is not deleted after creating the event then close the app and then again open the app remove the event from there.

Comment: Couldn't understand your problem. Can you elaborate more on that issue ?  One more thing to say, You can't handle app func when app is terminated. So if you terminate the app, then none of func will take place. That's why your deletion is not working at that time, it seems.

Answer (score 0):

try this code, its working for me,

```
EKEventStore *store = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

            [store requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
                if (!granted) return;
                EKEvent* eventToRemove = [store eventWithIdentifier:[eventIdendifier objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
                if (eventToRemove) {
                    [eventToRemove setCalendar:[store defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];

                    NSError* err = nil;

                    [store removeEvent:eventToRemove span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:YES error:&err];

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                        [eventIdendifier removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

                    });
                }
            }];
```

i have give eventIdentifier value, its NSMutableArray value. first you add the event in Event Store you had each event got each event identifier value, its automatically save to eventIdentifier and get the identifier value method is below,

```
EKEventStore *store = [EKEventStore new];

    if ([store respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAccessToEntityType:completion:)])
    {
        /* iOS Settings > Privacy > Calendars > MY APP > ENABLE | DISABLE */
        [store requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)
         {
             if ( granted )
             {
                 NSPredicate *predicate = [store predicateForEventsWithStartDate:date1 endDate:[date1 dateByAddingTimeInterval:23.96 * 60.0 * 60.0] calendars:nil];
                 NSMutableArray *eventsVal = (NSMutableArray *)[store eventsMatchingPredicate:predicate];

                 for (int i = 0; i<eventsVal.count; i++) {
                     [eventIdendifier addObject:[[eventsVal objectAtIndex:i] eventIdentifier]];
                 }

             }
         }];

    }
```

its predicate the start date to end date check then got all events particular date and also add object from eventIdentifier value if the value help to show event Values, remove events etc

hope its helpful

Comment: used it but it is throwing error  Use of undeclared identifier 'eventIdendifier' how to remove this

Comment: before your suggestion i was trying the following code         EKEventStore* store = [EKEventStore new];
        [store requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
            if (!granted) { return;}
            EKEvent* eventToRemove = [store eventWithIdentifier:savedEventId];
            if (eventToRemove) {
                NSError* error = nil;
                [store removeEvent:eventToRemove span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:YES error:&error];
            }
        }];   there is no error but it doen not grants permission simply return

Comment: sorry, eventIdentifier is NSMutableArray, when you add the event you had got the event identifier value from the eventStore, save the event identifier value then remove the identifier value, its the best to remove the event. try it

Comment: okay i'm trying but i am very new to programming i dont know how to implement it, plz help

Comment: Okay i'll try this one and let you know its working or not :) thanks

Comment: thankyou so much its working :) but there is one problem that events get deleted from icalender only when app is open and also we are getting data from server so data is not deleted after creating the event then close the app and then again open the app remove the event from there.

Comment: reload the tableview or any view its deleted at the current time, welcome

Comment: Okay i'll try this... will tell you